# Compile or build Library’s build.gradle file when we compile or build Main project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am having one Library Project which is developed by me, inside Library, in gradle file I have mentioned one specific task, like show the root project and library project path.

Now when I am adding this Library to my other project and when I build the project, I wanted to build the Library gradle file so that it performs the task which I have mentioned in Library gradle file.

There is one library inside that library, I have one plugin,

```
// automatic code generation
apply plugin: 'jsonschema2pojo'

// automatic code generation
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:0.5.1'
        //classpath 'org.jsonschema2pojo:jsonschema2pojo-gradle-plugin:latest.integration'

    }
}

// automatic code generation
// Each configuration is set to the default value
jsonSchema2Pojo {
    generateBuilders = false
    usePrimitives = false
    source = files("${rootProject.projectDir}/schema/schema/")
    targetPackage = 'com.model'
    propertyWordDelimiters = [] as char[]
    useLongIntegers = false
    useDoubleNumbers = true
    includeHashcodeAndEquals = true
    includeToString = true
    annotationStyle = 'gson'
    customAnnotator = 'org.jsonschema2pojo.NoopAnnotator'
    includeJsr303Annotations = true
    sourceType = 'json'
    boolean removeOldOutput = true
    String outputEncoding = 'UTF-8'
    boolean useJodaDates = false
    boolean useCommonsLang3 = false
    boolean initializeCollections = true
} 

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    //  code generation
    compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
    compile 'commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6'
    compile 'javax.validation:validation-api:1.1.0.CR2'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Now, I want this code or Gradle to build while I add this library to my other project.

Comment: Did you try to add to dependencies `compile project(':mysuperlibrary')`?

Comment: @DeKaNszn don't want add manually, please read the question again, i want this library project needs to set on main project and while you build your main project it should build library project, this will work when you add module manually, but when you will do this by creating gradle and add that library to any main project it wont work.

Comment: If you want to force build for library module, you should manually add it as dependency for app module, or dependency for build task of app module

Comment: how to achieve this, dependency for build task of app module ?

Comment: Add `build.dependsOn TASKNAME` in your app module build.gradle

Comment: @DeKaNszn can you add that task on my code given above ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this setup? To provide a set of parameters to the library based on the main project?

Comment: @FcoP. what i am going to do is just build the library gradle when i build my main project so the code which is available in library gradle jsonSchema2Pojo will automatically builds and in main project i dont have to write that code library will manage that jsonSchema2Pojo task in gradle file, if you want i can give a demo what i am trying to do.

Comment: That would be great